# simple radiobutton action in android

Tags: android

### I am trying to make a set of `RadioButtons` visible `onclick` of a `button`

---

- There are two set of radio buttons
- Until i click select days set of buttons displaying days must be
  invisible
- When i click selectdays then they must be visible

[image]

**What i have tried::**

- I have set up the entire setup
- But dont know how to achieve the action i mentioned above

---

**buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    android:id="@+id/ChangeBreakfastFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_background_for_rounded_corners_white_bkg" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image_view_background_white_background"
            android:padding="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_lunch_first_row_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/lunch_button_id"
                    android:layout_width="97dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_rounded_corners_buffetofferings"
                    android:text="Breakfast" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lunch_from_textview_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lunch_button_id"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="From"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/from_lunch_edit_text_id"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lunch_to_textview_id"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/lunch_button_id"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="To"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <requestFocus />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/to_lunch_edit_text_id"
                    android:layout_width="55dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_type_of_days"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_lunch_first_row_id"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Weekdays"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Weekends"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Select Days"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout_individualdays"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout_type_of_days"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Mon"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Tue"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Wed"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Thu"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Fri"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Sat"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Sun"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity.java**

```
public class BuffetOfferings_MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    FragmentManager manager;
    FragmentTransaction transaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buffet_offerings_fragment_main_reference);

        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1 breakfast_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1 lunch_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu1();
        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1 dinner_fragment=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu1();

        manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID,breakfast_fragment, "breakfast_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID,lunch_fragment, "lunch_menu1_fragment");
        transaction.add(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID,dinner_fragment, "dinner_menu1_fragment");

        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void BreakfastRedMenu1(View V){
        Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2  breakfast_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.BREAKFAST_LAYOUT_ID, breakfast_fragment1, "Tag1");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void LunchRedMenu1(View V){
        Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu2  lunch_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_lunch_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.LUNCH_LAYOUT_ID, lunch_fragment1, "Tag2");
        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void DinnerRedMenu1(View V){
        Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu2  dinner_fragment1=new Buffet_offerings_dinner_menu2();
        transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.DINNER_LAYOUT_ID, dinner_fragment1, "Tag3");
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java**

```
public class Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2 extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

---

### After EDIT

**Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java**

```
public class Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2 extends Fragment{

    RadioGroup radioGroup;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2, container, false);


        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);        

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){  
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                   if(checkedId == R.id.DinnerRG_ID)
                   {
                      getActivity().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
          }
        });


        return view;
    }



}
```

**Log** ::

```
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.project.findmybuffet.Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.onCreateView(Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java:25)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-15 11:43:02.391: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hide your Radiobuttons in the second row by defaut and make them visible onClick of your desired buttons.

Comment: @ amalBit ........ Can you please edit my code as your answer with your input

Comment: Wait ill try to give an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch the IDs like,

```
view.findViewById(...);
```

**Original Answer:**

In your XML layout:

- Change the name of the second radio group to *radioGroup2*.
- Lets now make the second radioGroup invisible by adding: **android:visibility="gone"**

Now if you run the app, you will only get the first row of contents. Lets now add the code to make the radio button visible on listening to the selectDays click:

- Inside that fragments onCreateView():

  ```
  RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
  radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){  
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
             if(checkedId == R.id.**#**){
                findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2).setVisibility(View.visible);
             }
    }
  });
  ```

**Note:**

- Its a must to give unique ID to all the xml views so that we can access them during runtime.
- **#** is the id of the selectDays radioButton.

Comment: [+1] i upvoted the answer .... thanks for this input ....... can you look at the updated question i made some changes

Comment: @ amalBit .....How you diagonised the error abut that view .... i just want to understand ... as i am a newbie ....

Comment: Fragments should access the UI from their own view inflation because, they have to be reused. For eg. if we could acess the activity's view, then we cannot use this fragment with another activity.